# Has a scientific consensus been reached concerning the formation of the Grand Canyon?

Tags: geology, earth-history, rivers, stratigraphy

new student of Oceanography here!

I'm studying Earth Science right now, and I found conflicting reporting re: the formation of the Grand Canyon; whether it was formed singularly by the Colorado River over millions of years, or if it was formed by other processes with the river only filling into it relatively recently.

Is there a consensus yet in geology with regard to the Grand Canyon's geologic history? If so, could you share resources that help explain it?

Thank you so much!

Comment: I thought until today that the river cuts into a rapidly rising thick crust: e.g. https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1029/2012TC003107 and references. Isn't there consenus on that ? I am not a specialist.

Comment: Discussion of the reasons for the rise: https://pubs.geoscienceworld.org/gsa/geology/article/38/7/671/130346/The-enigmatic-rise-of-the-Colorado-Plateau and https://www.nps.gov/grca/learn/nature/grca-geology.htm

Comment: You have a few sources and what seems to be the current consensus on the forming of that erosional structure. What are those "other processes" (with links) you mentioned ?

Answer (score 2):

> I'm studying Earth Science right now, and I found conflicting reporting re: the formation of the Grand Canyon; whether it was formed singularly by the Colorado River over millions of years, or if it was formed by other processes with the river only filling into it relatively recently.

Yes, it was formed by other processes with the river only excavating into it relatively recently.

The [Grand Canyon National Park Service](https://www.nps.gov/grca/index.htm) describe the events involved in the formation of the Grand Canyon widely. The sequence of events was as follows:

- Emplacement of an igneous and metamorphic body.
- Sedimentation over the igneous and metamorphic body.
- Uptlift of the complex by tectonic forces forming Colorado Plateau.
- Excavation of the Plateau by Colorado River.

[**Read full explanation at Grand Canyon National Park website**](https://www.nps.gov/grca/learn/nature/grca-geology.htm).